# How can I set ColorStream size to my custom size that is not 640x480

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

What I want to do is

```
this.colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(350, 600, dpiX, dpiY, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
            this.image1.Source = this.colorBitmap;
```

I'm making microsoft kinect program. and i want to show color frame that size is 350x640.
but there're only selections in ColorImageFormat are 640x480 and 1280x960

(you know, InfraredResolution640x480Fps30 or RawBayerResolution1280x960Fps12 something..)

when I try below, the stream is looks very weird. full of noise

```
nui.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
            this.colorPixels = new byte[nui.ColorStream.FramePixelDataLength];
            this.colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(350, 600, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
            this.image1.Source = this.colorBitmap;
```

Comment: Do you want to crop the bitmap, or just resize it?

Comment: What ever i can get 350x600 size stream. What do you recommend?